# Boost foreach conflicts with Q_FOREACH (Qt) and moc generation?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, point-cloud-library

I have a program edited in Vs 2008 using some libraries such as Qt and Point Cloud Library (PCL).

PCL has a 3rd party library which contains boost.

However, some errors appeared after compiling:

> 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp(926)
>   : error C3083: 'Q_FOREACH': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a
>   type 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp(926)
>   : error C2039: 'tag' : is not a member of 'boost' 1>C:\Program
>   Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp(926)
>   : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tag' 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp(1399) : error C3083: 'Q_FOREACH': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a
>   type 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp(1399) : error C2039: 'tag' : is not a member of 'boost' 1>C:\Program
>   Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp(1399) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tag' 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp(1254) : error C3083: 'Q_FOREACH': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a
>   type 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp(1254) : error C2039: 'tag' : is not a member of 'boost' 1>C:\Program
>   Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp(1254) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tag' 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp(1012)
>   : error C3083: 'Q_FOREACH': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a
>   type 1>C:\Program Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp(1012)
>   : error C2039: 'tag' : is not a member of 'boost' 1>C:\Program
>   Files\PCL
>   1.5.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp(1012)
>   : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tag'

For the first problem, the error location in the source file is:

```
template<typename SuperMeta,typename TagList>
inline boost::mpl::true_* boost_foreach_is_noncopyable(
  boost::multi_index::detail::random_access_index<SuperMeta,TagList>*&,
  boost::foreach::tag) // <-------------error here for the first compile error.
{
  return 0;
}
```

I think maybe this indicates that the `Q_FOREACH` conflicts with the boost foreach.

But I do not know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you build you project with `CONFIG += no_keywords` set?

Comment: Yes! it works as you said. thanks

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Qt defines a `foreach` macro (`#define foreach Q_FOREACH`) which conflicts with the `boost::foreach` namespace.

The easiest ways to solve it is to either include Boost before Qt or simply undefine the Qt's macro before including the boost's header file. I prefer the second since it won't need extra  documentation (`// remember to include Boost before Qt`), and it is easier to manage in nested header files and if you use precompiled headers.

```
#undef foreach
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
```

This option is less invasive than disabling Qt's keywords (compilation flag `-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS`) and can be applied only in the affected files if wanted. It won't affect the use of `Q_FOREACH` (obviously if you use the Qt's `foreach` it will fail). It also works independently that Qt is included before or after `<boost/foreach.hpp>`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting compiler flag `-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS`, disables the clash between boost and qt!

But then you need to replace the qt keywords in your code like `slots`, `signals`, `emit` ..., see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188432/cdk-collides-with-qt-signals).

(I got this message when introducing boost::multi_index container in my project.)

- (For qmake projects `CONFIG += no_keywords` does this.)
- (For cmake project `add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)` does this.)