# 'boost::Q_FOREACH' has not been declared

Tags: c++, qt, boost

In my code I use boost (1.52) and qt (4.8.3) and the first compilation error I have is the following

```
D:\qt\4.8.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include/QtCore/qglobal.h:2439:21: error: 'boost::Q_FOREACH' has not been declared
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Can you post the code? It's probably a clash between Qt's `foreach` macro and something in boost.

Comment: There is some kind of define available in Qt to prevent it defining "keywords" like `foreach`. See `CONFIG += no_keywords` in .pro files.

Comment: Problem is there is no my code involved in this error.

Comment: There must be some minimal code you can post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by the conflict between boost and Qt. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686283/boost-foreach-conflicts-with-q-foreach-qt-and-moc-generation)

Someone suggested using CONFIG += no_keywords in your project file.

But I've also seen a ticket to fix this issue closed.. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6455
So not sure whether this could help your problem

Comment: Not using the Qt keywords is the correct answer. See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6131 for the long, sorry history of my failed attempts to get Qt and Boost.Foreach to play nicely.

Answer (score 11):

Start your .cpp-file with `#include <QObject>`.

For instance, this:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <QObject>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
```

... compiles to `error: 'boost::Q_FOREACH' has not been declared` whereas this:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
```

... compiles just fine.

---

`qglobal.h` (included by all Qt headers) creates a macro `#define foreach Q_FOREACH` which expands in references like `boost::foreach::foo` or `namespace foreach`, but only in references encountered after the macro declaration. Be defining the macro early all references are expanded in the same way.

I used `hashed_index.hpp` in the example because it happens to use the foreach namespace. It's ugly to rename a namespace but it doesn't affect the client code.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having this issue, another workaround is to have the Boost includes before the Qt includes