# Qt macro keywords cause name collisions

Tags: c++, qt, c-preprocessor, ncurses, ncurses-cdk

I am building an NCurses interface for my Qt project. I want to use CDK but I think the `signals` member of this struct is colliding with the Qt `signals` keyword.

```
/usr/include/linux/cdk.h:411: error: expected unqualified-id before 'protected'
```

How can I get CDK to work with Qt?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define the QT_NO_KEYWORDS macro, that disables the “signals” and “slots” macros.

If you use QMake:

```
 CONFIG += no_keywords
```

([Qt Documentation here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots))

If you’re using another build system, do whatever it needs to pass `-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS` to the compiler.

Defining QT_NO_KEYWORDS will require you to change occurrences of `signals` to `Q_SIGNALS` and `slots` to `Q_SLOTS` in your Qt code.

If you cannot change all the Qt code, e.g. because you're using third-party libraries not being "keyword-clean", you could try to undefine "signals" locally before including cdk.h:

```
#undef signals
#include <cdk.h>
```

I'd recommend to use no_keywords though if possible, as it is less tedious and error-prone.

Comment: How does that 2nd suggestion work? `#define QT_NO_KEYWORDS` in a middle of a file will not magically undefine `signals` macro, will it? It'd need to be around Qt includes, not `cdk.h`, wouldn't it?

Comment: hyde: Oups, indeed. See, it’s error-prone ;) Removed the hint.