# Compilation error when compiling IFC++ and TBB

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, cad, ifc

I am trying to compile [IFC++](https://github.com/berndhahnebach/ifcplusplus/tree/master) under linux

I tried following the instructions but it seems the project is currently broken under linux. To get the main library to compile I had to add:

```
find_package(TBB REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(IfcPlusPlus PUBLIC TBB::tbb)
```

At the bottom of

```
IfcPlusPlus/CMakeLists.txt
```

This compiles and links. Then I tried compiling the example:

```
examples/SimpleViewerExampleQt
```

By running:

```
cmake -DIFCPP_SOURCE_DIR=../../ .. && make
```

This results in the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_small_object_pool.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_task.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/oneapi/tbb/parallel_for.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/parallel_backend.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/algorithm_impl.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/glue_execution_defs.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/execution:32,
                 from /home/makogan/Foresight/ifcplusplus/examples/SimpleViewerExampleQt/../../IfcPlusPlus/src/ifcpp/model/StatusCallback.h:20,
                 from /home/makogan/Foresight/ifcplusplus/examples/SimpleViewerExampleQt/src/gui/TabReadWrite.h:22,
                 from /home/makogan/Foresight/ifcplusplus/examples/SimpleViewerExampleQt/src/main.cpp:31:
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:229:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  229 |     void emit() { }
      |               ^
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:231:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
  231 |     static void emit(const std::string &) { }
      |                      ^~~~~
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:231:22: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
  231 |     static void emit(const std::string &) { }
      |                     ~^~~~~
      |                      )
```

The source code throwing that error is perfectly fine so I think this is a bit of a red herring. What I don't know is what I might be doing wrong when compiling and/or setting up the cmake arguments. There's no documentation on how to get the example running so I am guessing.

As the comments suggest, it does seem the problem stems from the QT macro. I did try modifying the CMAKE file of the project by adding this line:

`target_compile_definitions(SimpleViewerExampleQt PUBLIC QT_NO_KEYWORDS)`

But I am getting a bunch of errors of this ilk instead:

```
/home/makogan/Foresight/ifcplusplus/examples/SimpleViewerExampleQt/build/src/moc_IfcPlusPlusSystem.cpp:208:5: error: no matching function for call to 'activate'
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 4, nullptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I think disabling the macro is not sufficient.

Comment: The problem is that QT has a macro called emit, which is interfering with TBB.

Comment: See about halfway down [this QT documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) Possible solution provided right near the end of same page.

Comment: You can find a few solutions to the `emit` problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766441/using-library-which-has-a-function-name-already-defined-in-another-used-library)