# C++, Qt: Variable named "slots" in included external library

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, slot

I'm using Qt to write a desktop application that includes an external library. The problem is that I get an error when including the external library:

```
.../sc_containers.h:667: error: expected unqualified-id before ';' token
   sc_array_t         *slots;
                            ^
```

I successfully included the same library in a non-qt project before, so I assume that this error is related to the fact that Qt uses `slots` as a special keyword (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) in the Qt documentation).

Is there a way that I can use that external library in my program? Since this is not my own library, changing the variable name to something else isn't really an option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` (`-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS`) definition to your build will prevent Qt from defining `foreach`, `signals`, `slots` which may collide with other frameworks.

**Related answer**:

- [CDK Collides With Qt "signals"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188432/cdk-collides-with-qt-signals)

**Related doc**:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots

Comment: Alternative way: `CONFIG += no_keywords` in the .pro file.

Comment: @peppe yup, that's mentioned in the linked answer