# Qt and JACK incompatibility

Tags: qt, qt5, jack

I'm trying to put together a project using the Qt framework, and recently have been trying to integrate JACK audio. However, when adding

```
#include <jack/control.h>
```

along with any of the `QtCore` files (it does it for both `QCoreApplication` and `QObject`), the compiler gives me an error that stops any further progress... This error comes from one of the QtCore files that usually should compile without issue.

```
/home/user/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:97: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'public'

# define Q_SIGNALS public QT_ANNOTATE_ACCESS_SPECIFIER(qt_signal)
                    ^~~~~~
```

This seems to only happen when `jack/control.h` is included. I also noticed in the file itself that `signals` is used as a (seemingly irrelevant?) argument keyword. I tried changing the keyword without success.

Reversing the order of the `#include`'s just makes anything `jack`-dependent not work. Which also seems weird to me...

Any suggestions on how to move forward with this type of issue?

Comment: Try `CONFIG += no_keywords` (if using QMake) or define the corresponding defines manually, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188432/qt-macro-keywords-cause-name-collisions

Comment: The `no_keywords` setting can't work if I am using signals and slots, but using `#undef signals` before the `#include <jack/control.h>` did work just fine. Thank you!

Comment: extern "C" { #include <jack/control.h> } ???

Comment: @Deep thanks, will try it when I get the chance. The code finally ended up not working (despite keywords changed or `#undef`), the compiler rejects any use of the included class. I'm not familiar with `extern` so I can't predict how it'll act, I'll post the result tomorrow

Comment: @Deep doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work - same errors or other?

Comment: @Deep Same error. For some reason, the `#include <jack/jack.h>` works and its members are usable, while `#include <jack/control.h>` seems to have members declared (they are recognized) but the definitions do not get through - errors come up when compiling saying the members are not defined.