# C++ - Integration of CLIPS (rule engine)

Tags: c++, gcc, clips

I'm trying to integrate CLIPS into my C++ application (QT-project). I already have included the source and header files to the projects. I'm now trying to compile the downloaded source code to see if my basic call within main is working. I'm stuck with the error codes below and do not know to solve them. I also do not want to change the source code of CLIPS which should be just integrated.

```
void *env;

env = CreateEnvironment();



// The file hello.clp must be in the same directory
// as the CLIPS executable or you must specify the
// full directory path as part of the file name.

EnvLoad(env, "hello.clp");
EnvReset(env);
EnvRun(env,-1);
DestroyEnvironment(env);
```

Compiling the code leads to the errors:

> ...\function\core\object.h:113:
>   Fehler: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
>       SLOT_DESC *slots,

and

> ...\function\core\object.h:211:
>   Fehler: expected unqualified-id before ';' token *slots;

The error points to the code:

```
struct instance
  {
    ....
   INSTANCE_SLOT **slotAddresses,
                 *slots;
  };
```

and

```
struct defclass
  {
    ...
   SLOT_DESC *slots,
             **instanceTemplate;
    ...
  };
```

This is not my own code I'm just trying to use the functionality provided by CLIPs and integrate it into my own application. [CLIPS Programming Guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v640/apg.pdf)

Comment: Qt defines a global macro `slots` that interferes with the variable names CLIPS chose.
. See this question: [Qt macro keywords cause name collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188432/qt-macro-keywords-cause-name-collisions)

Comment: `slots` keyword in QT

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> *1.1 C++ Compatibility*
>
> The  CLIPS  source  code  can  be  compiled  using  either  an  ANSI  C  or  C++  >compiler. To  make CLIPS API calls from a C++ program, it is usually easier to do the integration by compiling the CLIPS  source  files  as  C++  files.  This  removes  the  need  to  make  an extern  "C"declaration  in your C++ program for the CLIPS APIs. Some compilersallow you to specify the whether a file should be compiled as C or C++ code based on the file extension. Other compilersallow you to explicitly  specify  which  compiler  to  use  regardless  of  the  extension

**(e.g. in gcc the option “-x c++” will compile .c files as C++ files)**

> For compilers that exclusively use the file extension to determine whether the >file should be compiled as a C or C++ code,it's necessary to changethe .c >extension of the CLIPS source files to a .cppextension.

Comment: Hey I already wrote a script which just changes all *.c to *.cpp therefore QT should normally compile it as c++, shouldn't it?

Comment: Using Qtcreator ? Look at your build config

Comment: Changing the .c in .cpp as for me isn't a good idea